# How to change the Text of a TextView defined in one apk from other apk in same workspace but different package

Tags: android, textview

I have a CoreApp in that i have defined a Custom Text View with id as **tV1CoreAppMainActivity** .
I have a FeatureApp in which i have included that CoreApp as jar through AddExternalJars.
Both are in same workspace but different Apk.
I want to change the property of that Text Field of Core app through following code in FeatureApp."

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.example.coreapp.R.id.tV1CoreAppMainActivity);
if(tv != null) 
{
    tv.setText("Changed from Feature");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

But i am getting the error as **com.example.coreapp.R cannot be resolved to a variable**,
where **com.example.coreapp** is the core app package and **com.example.featureapp** is feature app package.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to include it as a jar? If they are under the same project in the workspace but in different packages, you should just be able to do a simple import on the R.java in your 'FeatureApp'

```
import com.example.coreapp.R;
```

and then access it like so:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tV1CoreAppMainActivity);
```

Sorry if I missed the point in your question, I had a little trouble understanding exactly what was going on.

Comment: I solve the issue. By the way thanks for your answer. My question was actually different from what you have answered. Your answer will work when they are in same project, but for me they are in different project. So, we need to simply add coreapp as a jar and can use it in feature app.

Comment: Ahhh right, I see. Glad you got it sorted! Good luck with the rest of your project